# Jest with Enzyme, why is `toHaveBeenCalled` not triggering in my React Component test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm working on a unit test in a React application that verifies a passed in prop function is being conditionally called based on another props value. I'm utilizing Typescript/Enzyme/Jest in my application and am using a `Root` wrapper around the component I'm testing to inject the Redux store (and override initial state if desired).

```js
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import Login from "src/components/auth/Login";
import Root from "src/Root";

let wrapped: ReactWrapper;

let defaultProps = {
  signIn: jest.fn(),
  token: null,
};

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapped = mount(
    <Root>
      <Login {...defaultProps} />
    </Root>
  );
});

describe("on mount", () => {
  describe("if no token is supplied to the props", () => {
    it("will call the props.signIn() function", () => {
      expect(defaultProps.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

When I run the test the `toHaveBeenCalled()` (as well as `toBeCalled()`, tried both) are not registering any calls. However, I have supplied a `console.log` statement that is getting triggered within the same conditional that the `signIn()` function lives.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { AuthState, JWT } from "src/components/auth/types";
import { signIn } from "src/redux/auth";

interface Props {
  signIn: () => Promise<void>;
  token: null | JWT;
}

class Login extends React.Component<Props> {
  /**
   * Sign the user in on mount
   */
  public componentDidMount(): void {
    if (!this.props.token) {
      console.log("GETTING HERE");
      this.props.signIn();
    }
  }

  public render(): JSX.Elemeent {
    // ... More code
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AuthState) => {
  return {
    token: state.auth.token;
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signIn })(Login);
```

I've gone through several related posts/articles but all of the different configurations, such as traversing enzyme to get the direct prop or utilizing `spyOn`, have failed.

The only thing I can figure that's different is my wrapping of the `Login` component with `Root`, but considering I can see the `console.log` being triggered this seems like a complete shot in the dark.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being me forgetting to place the override via `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` in the `connect` function. This was causing my passed in `signIn` function to be overridden by the `signIn` action imported in the file. Updating with `ownProps` and conditionally utilizing the passed in value fixes the issue:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: AuthState, ownProps: Props) => {
  return {
    token: ownProps.token || state.auth.token;
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>, ownProps: Props) => {
  return {
    signIn: ownProps.signIn || (() => { return dispatch(signIn()) })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to wait for component to mount, so:

```
it("will call the props.signIn() function", (done) => {
  setImmediate(() => {
    expect(defaultProps.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done()
  });
});
```

Comment: You might not get accurate results when you've multiple tests as you've declared `signIn: jest.fn(),` globally. You might want to change it's reference in beforeEach.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately that didn't work. It's still coming back with no triggered calls. And thank you for the suggestion with the beforeEach.

Comment: Is enzyme vastly being used in your project? It doesn't give any hooks to cater this problem. If you can use `@testing-library/react` that is far better one.

Comment: Can you try with the shallow wrapper. Also what does your root component does?

Comment: Can you try setTimeout with maybe 50ms instead of setImmediate. Yes try with shallow mounting as well.

Comment: This thread might be helpful as well: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1581

Comment: shallow wrapper produces the same results. Setting a timeout also produces the same results. The `Root` element simply adds the redux store and a way for me to override the initial value. As mentioned in the original post, I can see the `console.log` firing from the Component, so the Component is mounting correctly and the `token` is indeed null. I'll look over that article you sent @MuhammadAli

Comment: The problem actually was with the store. I'll have to update the question and add an answer. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Oops, no worries :)

Comment: I see, so connect was overriding your `signIn` prop.